# RemoveAttributes not doing anything

Tags: linq-to-xml

Any idea why RemoveAttributes isn't working?

```
foreach (XElement myItem in _list_XEle)
{
    MyObj temp = new MyObj();
    XElement myCopy = new XElement(myItem);
    myCopy.RemoveAttributes();

    // other stuff
    temp.String1 = myCopy.ToString();

    _list_MyObj.Add(temp);
}
```

After this code, the attributes remain. Not sure if relevant, but all attributes are prefixed by namespaces.

many thanks

Comment: Just to clarify - it's only the xmlns attributes that remain

Answer (score 0):

I just guess what is your case, but given the following XML:

```
<content xmlns:ns="SomeNameSpace" xmlns="DefaultNamesSpace">
    <customer ns:id="123" ns:attr="abc" />
    <customer ns:id="125" ns:attr="fgr" />
</content>
```

I wrote a  sample code similar than yours:

```
var dom = XElement.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

XNamespace ns = "DefaultNamesSpace";
foreach (var myItem in dom.Elements(ns + "customer"))
{
    XElement myCopy = new XElement(myItem);
    myCopy.RemoveAttributes();
    //myCopy.Name = myCopy.Name.LocalName;
}
```

If you run as is, the myCopy would be `<customer xmlns="DefaultNamesSpace" />` because attributes removed, but the element still in the default namespace, that is marked as well. To remove that namespace attribute you should change the name of your copied XElement to an empty namespace. If you uncomment the last line, your XElement will be `<customer />`